# Create folder structure in all subdirectories (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I've written the code attached below. This code is intended to create a folder structure in all of the subdirectories within a defined directory (location). This code worked when I tested it in the folder "C:/test/" however, when I tried to run it in the real location, it did not work. All of the subdirectories have the following name structure: example: "173-A-55-US2".

Any ideas why the batch file worked in the test location however he did not work in the real location?

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "location=C:\Users\Eitan Waks\Dropbox\PATENT\Waks & Co\Bressler"

for /d %%d in (%location%\*) do (
  md "%%d\Checklists"
  md "%%d\Client"
  md "%%d\Drafts"
  md "%%d\Forms"
  md "%%d\Final"
  md "%%d\IDS"
  md "%%d\USPTO"
)
```

Comment: What exactly happened in the real location? Did you get any error messages? Did any directories get created at all? Have you tested with a directory that contains spaces and ampersand (which look like trouble)?

Comment: Use quotes: `("%location%\*")`. You could find the error yourself by simply removing `@echo off`.